# How destroy objects created with MEF

Tags: ioc-container, mef, caliburn.micro, memory-management

Hi I use MEF and caliburn.micro in WPF app. I would like know how can I destroy instaces created with MEF.

**For example simple shell:**

```
 [Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShellViewModel
    {

        protected override void OnInitialize()
        {
            ShowLogOn();
            base.OnInitialize();
        }

        //first screen
        public void ShowLogOn()
        {
            var vm = IoC.Get<ILogOnViewModel>();
            ActivateItem(vm);
        }

        //second screen
        public void ShowMessenger(Account account)
        {
            ActiveItem.Deactivate(true);
            var vm = IoC.Get<IMessengerViewModel>();
            vm.Account = account;
            ActivateItem(vm);
        }

  }
```

**First screen**

```
[Export(typeof(ILogOnViewModel))]
public class LogOnViewModel : Screen,ILogOnViewModel
{
   User user=new User();
}
```

**Second screen:**

```
  [Export(typeof(IMessengerViewModel))]
            public class MessengerViewModel : Screen, IViewModelIdentity,
                IMessengerViewModel, IHandle<Rp>, IHandle<string>
            {..}
```

WPF app start with first screen associated with ILogOnViewModel interface. Then I deactivate this screen and activate second screen associated with IMessengerViewModel interface.

I check memory usage with ANTS Mememory profiler but instace of ILogOnViewModel is still alive also instace of class User is alive.

I am newbie in IoC, DI... all class which are exported with MEF must live during the whole WPF application lifetime cycle?

Other example, I create new wpf window with window manager.

```
[Export(typeof(IChatViewModel))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ChatViewModel : Screen, IViewModelIdentity, 
    IChatViewModel, IHandle<Rp>, IHandle<DetailData>
{}
```

ChatViewModel is WPF Window.

Create instance of IChatViewModel:

```
private IWindowManager _windowManager;
var chatScreen = IoC.Get<IChatViewModel>();
_windowManager.Show(chatScreen);
```

Then I close (click on X (close) button on window) WPF Window, ChatViewModel is deactivated
but instace of this class is still alive.

It exist way how kill/destroy this instaces?

Answer (score 1):

The MEF container is responsible for managing the lifetime of your exports, so regardless of which `CreationPolicy` is used (default is `Shared`), the final call to the container's `Dispose` method will dispose of any `Export` instances (which wrap your actual class instances).  Also, calling `Dispose` on an `Export` instance will cause the actual class instance to dispose also.

The thing to remember, is the GC is looking at the object graph and determining if there are 0 or more references to that particular instance, because a reference is maintained by the MEF `CompositionContainer` (wrapped up in an `Export`) it won't dispose of that item.

If you enforce that `IDisposable` is implemented in your plugins, e.g.

```
public interface ILogOnViewModel : IDisposable { }
```

And ensure that when implementing the dispose pattern, you allow it to be called multiple times:

```
public void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && !disposed)
    {
        // Clean up?
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SurpressFinalize(this);
}
```

You can then safely call `Dispose` on your instance of your `ILogOnViewModel` implementation without causing problems when the actual container disposes.

Comment: Yes, but the object never gets freed up until the container is disposed, which is quite a limitation.